# How to activate a hover button in bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have multiple buttons in my page implemented through bootstrap 3 and html. The button having the name "Water" should open up other buttons once the mouse is hovered over it and should hide them once the mouse moves away from it. Currently the buttons open once the "Water' button is clicked.
i have implemented the hover functionality which can be seen in the javascript and html but it does not seem to work. How can i adjust the divs or classes so that it works?

Here is the code and fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/2vok9hLw/

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {   
    $('#create_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#create_tab').tab('show')
    })

    
    $('#login_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#login_tab').tab('show')
    })

     $('#create_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#create1_tab').tab('show')
    })
    $(".hover_btn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    })

    
    $(".hover_btn").hover(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab2default1").css("opacity","1");
    })

    
    $(".hover_btn").mouseleave(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab2default1").css("opacity","0");
    })
    
    $(".hover_btn2").hover(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab2default1").css("opacity","1");
    })
    
    $(".hover_btn2").mouseleave(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab2default1").css("opacity","0");
    })

});
```

```css
  #customTab a {
            padding: 0;
        }

        .flex {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: baseline;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        @media (max-width: 576px) {
            .container {
                padding: 0;
            }

            .btn {
                padding: 3px 6px;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            .flex .panel-default{
                margin-right: 4px;
            }
            .flex .panel-default>.panel-heading{
                padding: 0;
            }
            .flex .panel-default>.panel-body .btn:last-child{
                margin-top: 4px;
            }
        }

        .btn-dark {
            background-color: #343a40;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .btn-dark:hover,.btn.focus, .btn:focus {
            color: #fff;
        }
        .btn.focus, .btn:focus,.btn:active,.btn:hover , .active >a .btn{
            color: #fff;
            background: blue;
        }
        .nav-tabs{
            border: none;
        }
        
        .hover_btn{
            background-image: url(air.jfif);
            background-size: cover;
            color: #000;
            height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
        }
        
        .hover_btn:hover{
            background-image: url(air.jfif);
            background-size: cover;
            color: #000;
            height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
            opacity: 0.9;
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<main>
   <div><br></br>Some text.</div>
        <div class="container" id="customTab">
            </div>
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border: none;">
                        <li><span class="btn btn-info btn-lg ">main heading</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <br></br>
        <div class="container" id="customTab">
                    <ul class="nav " style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border: none;">
                        <li><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="hover_btn" >Water</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                    class="btn btn-info">a</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab3default" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                    class="btn btn-info">b<br>b2</br>
                                     </span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab4default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">c</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab5default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">d</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab6default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">e<br>e2</br>
                             
                            
                        </span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content hover_btn2">
                    <div class= "hover_btn2" >
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1default"  >
                            <div class="flex ">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">1</span></li>
                                        </ul>
                              
                                <div class=" panel-default">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li a id="login_btn"><span class="btn btn-info" data-target="#signin" data-toggle="modal">2</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="signin" role="dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="well">
                                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                                <li class="active"><a id="login_tab" href="#login" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
                                                <li class=""><a id="create_tab" href="#create" data-toggle="tab">Reviews</a></li>
                                                <li class=""><a id="create1_tab" href="#create1" data-toggle="tab">Workflows</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                            
                                            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content ">
                                                <div class="tab-pane active in" id="login">
                                               <iframe src= "" style="border:none;width:1450px;height:600px;" >
                                           
                                               </iframe>     
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="tab-pane fade.in" id="create">
                                                 <p>
                                                 hello
                                                 </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="tab-pane fade.in" id="create1">
                                                 <p>
                                                 hellosss
                                                 </p>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" >Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>    

                                   
                                </div>
                                <div >
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li href="#tab2default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">4</span></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <br></br>
                                        <div class="flex tab-pane fade" id="tab2default3">
                                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                                        <li href="#tab22default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                                    class="btn btn-info">4</span>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                              
                                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                                        <li href="#tab222default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                                    class="btn btn-info">5</span>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                               
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2default">
                            <div class="flex">
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab3default1" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">6</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3default1">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal7">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal8">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab3default2" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">7</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3default2">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal9">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal10">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab3default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">8</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3default3">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal11">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal12">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3default">
                            <div class="flex">
                          
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab5default2" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">9</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5default2">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal21">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal22">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab5default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">10</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5default3">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal23">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal24">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4default">
                            <div class="flex">
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab6default1" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">11</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6default1">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal25">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal26">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab6default2" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">12</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6default2">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal27">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal28">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab6default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">13</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6default3">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal29">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal30">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may you hover water and tell me if that was your expected result? (run snippet

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {   
    $('#create_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#create_tab').tab('show')
    })

    
    $('#login_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#login_tab').tab('show')
    })

     $('#create_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#create1_tab').tab('show')
    })
    $(".hover_btn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    })

    
    $(".hover_btn").mouseenter(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab1default").css("opacity","1");
    })

    
    $(".hover_btn").mouseleave(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab1default").css("opacity","0");
    })
    
    $(".hover_btn2").hover(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab2default1").css("opacity","1");
    })
    
    $(".hover_btn2").mouseleave(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab2default1").css("opacity","0");
    })

});
```

```css
  #customTab a {
            padding: 0;
        }

        .flex {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: baseline;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        @media (max-width: 576px) {
            .container {
                padding: 0;
            }

            .btn {
                padding: 3px 6px;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            .flex .panel-default{
                margin-right: 4px;
            }
            .flex .panel-default>.panel-heading{
                padding: 0;
            }
            .flex .panel-default>.panel-body .btn:last-child{
                margin-top: 4px;
            }
        }

        .btn-dark {
            background-color: #343a40;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .btn-dark:hover,.btn.focus, .btn:focus {
            color: #fff;
        }
        .btn.focus, .btn:focus,.btn:active,.btn:hover , .active >a .btn{
            color: #fff;
            background: blue;
        }
        .nav-tabs{
            border: none;
        }
        
        .hover_btn{
            background-image: url(air.jfif);
            background-size: cover;
            color: #000;
            height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
        }
        
        .hover_btn:hover{
            background-image: url(air.jfif);
            background-size: cover;
            color: #000;
            height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
            opacity: 0.9;
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<main>
   <div><br></br>Some text.</div>
        <div class="container" id="customTab">
            </div>
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border: none;">
                        <li><span class="btn btn-info btn-lg ">main heading</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <br></br>
        <div class="container" id="customTab">
                    <ul class="nav " style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border: none;">
                        <li><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab" id="test"><span class="hover_btn" >Water</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                    class="btn btn-info">aaaa</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab3default" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                    class="btn btn-info">b<br>b2</br>
                                     </span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab4default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">c</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab5default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">d</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab6default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">e<br>e2</br>
                             
                            
                        </span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content hover_btn2">
                    <div class= "hover_btn2" >
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1default"  >
                            <div class="flex ">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">1</span></li>
                                        </ul>
                              
                                <div class=" panel-default">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li a id="login_btn"><span class="btn btn-info" data-target="#signin" data-toggle="modal">2</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="signin" role="dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="well">
                                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                                <li class="active"><a id="login_tab" href="#login" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
                                                <li class=""><a id="create_tab" href="#create" data-toggle="tab">Reviews</a></li>
                                                <li class=""><a id="create1_tab" href="#create1" data-toggle="tab">Workflows</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                            
                                            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content ">
                                                <div class="tab-pane active in" id="login">
                                               <iframe src= "" style="border:none;width:1450px;height:600px;" >
                                           
                                               </iframe>     
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="tab-pane fade.in" id="create">
                                                 <p>
                                                 hello
                                                 </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="tab-pane fade.in" id="create1">
                                                 <p>
                                                 hellosss
                                                 </p>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" >Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>    

                                   
                                </div>
                                <div >
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li href="#tab2default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">4</span></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <br></br>
                                        <div class="flex tab-pane fade" id="tab2default3">
                                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                                        <li href="#tab22default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                                    class="btn btn-info">4</span>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                              
                                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                                        <li href="#tab222default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                                    class="btn btn-info">5</span>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                               
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2default">
                            <div class="flex">
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab3default1" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">6</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3default1">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal7">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal8">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab3default2" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">7</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3default2">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal9">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal10">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab3default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">8</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3default3">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal11">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal12">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3default">
                            <div class="flex">
                          
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab5default2" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">9</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5default2">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal21">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal22">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab5default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">10</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5default3">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal23">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal24">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4default">
                            <div class="flex">
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab6default1" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">11</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6default1">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal25">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal26">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab6default2" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">12</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6default2">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal27">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal28">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab6default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">13</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6default3">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal29">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal30">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

So, hover is doing the job for the hover and the blur, both of things, so one solution if you want to use .hover would be to use toggleClass with a class that have opacity 0 (toggleClass add a class if it dont exist and remove it if it exist)

Second thing, your query was selected on something like #tab2default1, after 5 min of looking for it i found out its not existing

My solution here: i used 2 function, one for mouseenter and other for the mouseleave (you already had it)

Comment: exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Ok let me edit my message to tell you what i changed then :)

Comment: Here you go! :)

Comment: i had #tab2default1 because i wanted to extend the hover functionality to all the buttons that are displayed when you run code for first time. can i do it with the adjustments you made by just changied the ID's? or if you could tell me any other way?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand, talking about the a, b , c, d button? they all need to pop up when you mouse enter the water element? if so, you can just add opacity to all of them in the mouseenter function yes, if it come from another button, just take id of the other button and do a second function, similary with other ids,

Comment: i meant the butons "aaa" "bb2" "c" "d" and "e2" should also pop out buttons when mouse hovers overs on each of them. so i can do that with their ids and duplicating the functions. right?

Comment: Duplicating a function to put the exact same things should be in a loop, but if you dont care, yes you can

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234370/discussion-between-rehan-and-dafuqi).